# Why Chrome is not rendering the page which it gets from socket output stream? Java

Tags: java, sockets, google-chrome, http, serversocket

Here is my code:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

class Server
{
     public static void main(String args[])
     {
          try
          {
                ServerSocket svr = new ServerSocket(8900);
                System.out.println("waiting for request");
                Socket s = svr.accept();
                System.out.println("got a request");
                InputStream in = s.getInputStream();
                OutputStream out = s.getOutputStream();

                int x;
                byte data[]= new byte[1024];

                x = in.read(data);

                String response  = "<html><head><title>HTML content via java socket</title></head><body><h2>Hi! Every Body.</h2></body></html>";
                out.write(response.getBytes());
                out.flush();

                s.close();
                svr.close();
                System.out.println("closing all");
          }
          catch(Exception ex)
          {
                System.out.println("Err : " + ex);
          }
     }
}
```

Running it I hope to go to Chrome right this : `127.0.0.1:8900` and get nicely looking piece of html, but actually Chrome is saying the following :

`This page isn’t working
127.0.0.1 sent an invalid response.
ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE`.

Whereas my `Server.java` is running as I want it to. The console in Eclipse says nicely after connection :

`waiting for request
got a request
closing all`.

So I am very stuck. Help me to figure that out, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The response you are writing is certainly not readable to chrome. Because it doesn't contain any information about response in header**

Your code is actually send response. You can check it by using `curl`.
Following code will help you to get the response in chrome.

```
        ServerSocket svr = new ServerSocket(8900);
        System.out.println("waiting for request");
        Socket s = svr.accept();
        System.out.println("got a request");
        InputStream in = s.getInputStream();
        OutputStream out = s.getOutputStream();

        int x;
        byte data[] = new byte[1024];

        x = in.read(data);

        String t = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n";
        byte[] bb = t.getBytes("UTF-8");
        out.write(bb);

        t = "Content-Length: 124\r\n";
        bb = t.getBytes("UTF-8");
        out.write(bb);
        t = "Content-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n";
        bb = t.getBytes("UTF-8");
        out.write(bb);

        String response = "<html><head><title>HTML content via java socket</title></head><body><h2>Hi! Every Body.</h2></body></html>";
        out.write(response.getBytes("UTF-8"));

        t = "Connection: Closed";
        bb = t.getBytes("UTF-8");
        out.write(bb);

        out.flush();

        s.close();
        svr.close();
        System.out.println("closing all");
```

**The vital thing if you change your `response` then you have to calculate the `Content-Length:` as it will be the length of your `response` byte[] and the byte[] of `Connection: Closed` string.**